# reorder the div vertically in small screen using twitter bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On the mobile template i want to position the contact widget at first inside the sidebar.  Please check this example. Is there any way to do that

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="col-md-9">
<p>main content goes here</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="sidebar-nav">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#" title="">Overview</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Mission and Vision</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Directors</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Management</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Structure</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="contact-widget">
 <h3>Contact Address</h3>
 <p>some address will go here</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add two navigation instead of one and add show hide class based on media Query. Its a simple method to get the desired result. Markup follows

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="sidebar-nav">
        <ul class="nav hideMobile">
            <li><a href="#" title="">Overview</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mission and Vision</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Directors</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Management</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Structure</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="contact-widget">
            <h3>Contact Address</h3>
            <p>some address will go here</p>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav showMobile">
            <li><a href="#" title="">Overview</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mission and Vision</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Directors</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Management</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Structure</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tricky way :) .